# Classic ASP adodb connection error on Vista

Tags: asp-classic, ado

When my classic asp page gets to this line of code

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
```

it throws an error http 500. I suppose ado is not correctly installed

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this line part of asp page? If so, this is not how it should be.

Comment: well, the actual line is:
<%
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
%>

Comment: enable classic asp errors to get a more details http://geekswithblogs.net/lance/archive/2007/02/14/106330.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript doesn't let you specify the type - everything is a variant so your code should read

Set cnn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Comment: Correct. `Dim cnn : Set cnn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")` is more likely what you want...

Comment: Who dim's anything in vbscript. It's not like you've got option explicit or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that ADO is not installed correctly.  Try connecting via the Universal Data Link.  You can follow the directions here. http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=81

You should be able to see whether you can connect or not.  If not, you'll get a much more detailed message than you got from ASP.